# Ultrasonic Anemometer -- editing dev board to create pcb?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, msp430

I want to design a PCB that uses TI's MSP430FR6043 microcontroller. The purpose is to make an ultrasonic anemometer.

The basic idea is that the MSP430 sends out a pulse to an ultrasonic transducer, and then listens for the signal on another transducer. It will measure the time-of-flight for the signal, and send that to an ESP32, which will calculate wind speed from the time-of-flight.

I'm terrible at circuit design, so I'm thinking about taking a shortcut by using TI's development board schematic. I would start with the existing PCB schematic, identify the circuits that I need to do the above, and delete all the other circuits/components. I would use the results to make a PCB design in Eagle.

I have two questions:

Is this a viable approach?

Which circuits in the existing development board are necessary for controlling the transducers, and what can I remove?

For context I'm including a link to the development board page, which has schematics.

[Dev board page](https://www.ti.com/tool/EVM430-FR6043)

[Direct link to schematics](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidrys5)

Comment: Hi and welcome to this site. Your approach is viable. It's a good practice in electronics to find and use something existing and modify it to your specific needs. But you need to find your own way of doing this. If you ask specific questions where people can clearly see that you were thinking about the problem, then you will get good answers.

Comment: How many do you want to make?  How accurate do you need the results?  I'm asking because that's a pretty complex circuit and perhaps there are simpler alternatives for you.  The manufacturers want you to use parts of the the evaluation board, and it's what everybody does (or use the application circuits in the datasheets) -- that's why they publish the schematics.

Comment: "Is this a viable approach?" Yes, no, maybe. You need to specify _the requirements_ in a live document before anything else. Then when these are fleshed out, you can start looking for suitable MCUs and wireless technologies. Regarding MCUs, you'll want one with the right computing power as well as the right hardware peripherals - you found one by TI but maybe there are competing vendors? (TI in general is always the last resort due to their non-existing customer support.) Regarding wireless, there's a lot of parameters both technical and market ones. Which countries will it be used in etc.

Comment: You could do that, which would take some effort. The CAD files are supplied in Altium by the looks of it, which is a rather expensive package. You could try importing it to (open source) Kicad rather than Eagle.

Comment: This sort of thing is done all the time. You are absolutely allowed and encouraged to use the development board as a starting point for your own board. Designers like it because it's easier; manufacturers also like it because you buy more chips from them if your work is easier. It's possible there could be some copyright concern if you copied someone else's product, but no *chip manufacturer* in their right mind would get upset about copying a development board.

Comment: In fact, if you only want to make one or two anemometers, you might even buy the development boards and put the development boards in the product!